# C# Migrations Create Automatic Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have a ASP.NET WEB API 
I have  model class

```
 {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? MessageTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ToPhone { get; set; }
    public int ToClientId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int SenderUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MessageTypeId")]
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }


}
```

and its DbContext

I want to Create this tables in sql server how can I make it?

Comment: The Infinite Number of Monkeys are rather busy at the moment working on their version of _Hamlet_ and so are unable to write code for you at the moment.  What research have you done? What have you tried? This things will help us help you.  Good luck!  _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: I tried Enable Automatic Migrations,But it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable migrations (`Enable-Migrations`), add migrations (`Add-Migrations`) and update the databse (`Update-Database`) which can do the job directly in the database or create an script for you. This is all done using the Nuget Package Manager console.

For more details see this page: [Entity Framework (EF) Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) (search for Code First Migrations articles).

You can get help about each command from the console, typing something like this:

```
get-help update-database
```

Comment: it only adds __MigrationHistory table

Comment: Please, follow a tutorial to learn to use it. It works like a charm. I've been using it from years. You must be missing some basic step.

Answer (score 0):

As @JotaBe said the tutorial works like a charm. But You can just have your tables in the database without migration(for Code First). Migrations are for making changes to the database and updating the database. A database can be created by adding model classes and creating a Database Context and adding that context as a connection string in your web.config.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Have you added your context as Connection string in web.config?

The first sub topic on this tutorial is all about creating a database and tables. Hope this helps.